# Webpack doesn't resolve json file correctly

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have defined following method in a Vue page:

```
getIsoCountryCode: function(country){
            console.log(countries);
            return "flag-icon-" + countries.getAlpha2Code(country, 'en');
        }
```

The function returns `flag-icon-undefined`, even though it works when I test it outside the Vue/Webpack environment.

Webpack config:

```
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require("vue-loader");
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./lib/team-page/team.js",
  devtool: "source-map",
  watch: true,
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      flag_icon_css: __dirname + "/node_modules/flag-icon-css/css/flag-icon.css"
    }
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public/lib"),
    filename: "team.js"
  },
  mode: "development",
  module: {
    rules: [{
      type: 'javascript/auto',
      test: /\.(json|html)/,
      exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
      use: [{
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: { name: '[name].[ext]' },
      }]
    },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: "vue-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
            {loader: "style-loader"},

          {
            loader: "css-loader"
          },
          {
            loader: "sass-loader"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
            {loader: "style-loader"},

          {
            loader: "css-loader"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: "babel-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '../assets/flags/[name].[ext]'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [new VueLoaderPlugin()]
 };
```

I checked in the debugger, and found this piece of code in the Webpack-compiled file:

```
var codes = __webpack_require__(/*! ./codes.json */ "./node_modules/i18n-iso-countries/codes.json");
```

It still points to the `node_modules` folder, even though I would have expected it to be in the bundle. (Edit: this doesn't seem to matter, axios is defined in the same way and that works as expected.)

I added the rule suggested [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6586) to my config file, but it still doesn't work.

Edit: to get it to work, you have to register the locale first. For English: `countries.registerLocale(require("i18n-iso-countries/langs/en.json"));`

Comment: How are you calling `getIsoCountryCode`? At the very least I would expect to see `flag-icon-undefined` as your return. Also seeing your `webpack.config.js` could help.

Comment: @Flowers4Life indeed, it is returning flag-icon-undefined. I've added the config file.

Comment: Have you called `countries.registerLocale(require("i18n-iso-countries/langs/en.json"));` ? They only show it in the first documentation sample, but I was getting undefined previously, then correct country rendering after including that line. I'm testing in a webpack environment as well.

Comment: @Flowers4Life I had just figured it out myself. It is now working indeed. Many thanks.